# Allowing remote connections for MySQL on Ubuntu 14

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I am trying to connect to MySQL using a program called Heidi, I want to use this instead of phpmyadmin. It's better than phpmyadmin and I figured it would be more secure than going to domain.com/phpmyadmin

I have added the following line to `etc/mysql/my.cnf` and restarted mysql but no luck.

`bind-address = MY IP ADDRESS`

I keep getting the error `Can't connect to MySQL server on (server ip)`

I know the port is right (3306) and the ip is definitely right, not sure what else to do

Answer (score 0):

First, confirm that `skip-networking` is commented out in your my.cnf.

You will also need to allow remote connections from your IP to your database.

```
GRANT ALL ON yourdatabase.* TO mysqluser@'yourip' IDENTIFIED BY 'yourpassword';
```

Lastly, confirm that your firewall is not blocking the connection.